# Solve the equation $\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{x^2+2x+7}-\sqrt{x^2+3}=(x+1)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, real-numbers, radicals

$\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{x^2+2x+7}-\sqrt{x^2+3}=(x+1)^2$

The equation I'm trying to solve is $x_1=-2$. But the equation has 2 roots. Can any one find $x_2$?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you asking? The second real root is an algebraic number which does not have a closed form.

Comment: I tried to find , but I am having trouble. Question from my teacher. Can you guide me find $x_2$?

Comment: You'll need to provide more context. It makes a difference whether the course is in abstract algebra vs. numerical methods, or hand calculations vs. CASs.

Comment: Of course, the context is hand calculations, with $x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Then you'll need to show what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: I have $\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{x^2+2x+7}-\sqrt{x^2+3}=(x+1)^2\\
\Leftrightarrow (x+2)\left ( \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x+3}+1} +\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+7}+\sqrt{x^2+3}}-x\right )=0$. What should I do now?

Comment: It's still not clear what you are actually trying to do. There is no closed form solution, as I wrote in the first comment. The best you can do symbolically is prove that it's an algebraic number and find its minimal polynomial - which turns out to have degree $14$. How exactly you calculate that polynomial is a matter of what was covered in the course, which you did not say. One way would be to use polynomial resultants to eliminate the radicals, but those are very laborious calculations to carry out by hand.

Comment: I understand what you say. Thank you for what you have shared.

Comment: In theory, you could get rid of all the square roots by multiplying the eight factors $(D\pm\sqrt A\pm\sqrt B\pm\sqrt C)$.  But then you end up with a polynomial whose degree is 16.

Comment: Yes, I have problem end up with a polynomial whose degree is $16$, It's too hard for me.  Wow, My problem is terrible! :D :D. Thanks!

Comment: Please add your comments into the question. This helps to get more context for your question and thereby you can hope to get it reopened.

Answer (score 3):

Almost everything was said in comments.

If you are allowed to plot the function
$$f(x)=\sqrt{x+3}+\sqrt{x^2+2x+7}-\sqrt{x^2+3}-(x+1)^2$$ you notice that is looks like a parabola.

So, as a try, make a series expansion around $x=-2$ to obtain
$$f(x)=\left(\frac{5}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}\right) (x+2)+\left(\frac{3}{14
   \sqrt{7}}-\frac{9}{8}\right) (x+2)^2+O\left((x+2)^3\right)$$

$$\frac{f(x)}{x+2}=\left(\frac{5}{2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}\right) +\left(\frac{3}{14
   \sqrt{7}}-\frac{9}{8}\right) (x+2)+O\left((x+2)^2\right)$$

Using the above, an *approximation*
$$x=\frac{2 \left(49+40 \sqrt{7}\right)}{3 \left(147-4 \sqrt{7}\right)}=\frac{2 \left(1189+868 \sqrt{7}\right)}{9213}=0.756651$$ Repeat the expansion around $x=\frac 34$
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{16} \left(-49+8 \sqrt{15}-4 \sqrt{57}+4
   \sqrt{145}\right)+$$ $$\left(-\frac{7}{2}-\sqrt{\frac{3}{19}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{15}}+
   \frac{7}{\sqrt{145}}\right)
   \left(x-\frac{3}{4}\right)+O\left(\left(x-\frac{3}{4}\right)^2\right)$$ from which
$$x =\frac 34+\frac{8265 \left(-49+8 \sqrt{15}-4 \sqrt{57}+4 \sqrt{145}\right)}{8
   \left(57855-1102 \sqrt{15}+870 \sqrt{57}-798 \sqrt{145}\right)}=0.748997$$ while the solution obtained by Newton method is $x=0.748996$.

Notice that this simplistic process is very close to the one Newton used to invent Newton method.